# TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'

Tags: python, flask

I want to test my API which enhanced the image. This is my code:

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route('/enhanced', methods=['POST'])
def enhanced():
    data = {'name': '','success': False}
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.files["image"].read()
        name = request.files['image'].name
        npimg = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        enhanced_img, crop_img = pipeline(img)
        cv2.imwrite(APP_ROOT+'/static/images/'+name+'_enhanced.jpg', enhanced_img)
        cv2.imwrite(APP_ROOT+'/static/images/'+name+'_crop_roi.jpg', crop_img)
        data['name'] = name
        data['success'] = True

    return flask.jsonify(data)
```

And this is how I test it in the terminal:

```
curl -X POST -F image=@/home/input/image.jpg 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/enhanced'
```

Then it appears this error:

```
File "/home/src/api.py", line 47, in enhanced
    cv2.imwrite(APP_ROOT+'/static/images/'+name+'_enhanced.jpg', enhanced_img)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'
```

I don't know how to solve this error, can anyone help me.

Comment: will it work if you save img before sending it to pipeline() ? If not, will it work to save npimg ?

Comment: @VadimPlăcintă yes, it works, I can save the image. I save it with this code: `cv2.imwrite(APP_ROOT+'/static/images/'+name+'_enhanced.jpg', img)`

Comment: then pipeline() does something, may be you should put it's code here, or maybe try to apply np.array(enhanced_img)

Comment: @VadimPlăcintă my pipeline code has a problem, I modified it and forget to change in this code. Problem solves, thank you.